# Ansible loop one COMPLEX array of objects looking for case in-sensitive matches in the second COMPLEX array

Tags: ansible

I have two complex objects with the following structures:

**ProgA_Users**

```json
{
  "Resources": [
    {
      "emails": [
        {
          "type": "work",
          "value": "Oscar.Warren@domain.local"
        }
      ],
      "id": "2939XYZ",
      "userName": "Oscar.Warren@domain.local@SOMEREALM"
    },
    {
      "emails": [
        {
          "type": "work",
          "value": "Alexandra.Savage@domain.local"
        }
      ],
      "id": "2032XYZ",
      "userName": "Alexandra.Savage@domain.local@SOMEREALM"
    }
  ]
}
```

**ProgB_Usrs**

```json
[
  {
    "DistinguishedName": "CN=Warren\\, Oscar J.,OU=Users,OU=Finance Division,OU=Departments,DC=domain,DC=local",
    "Name": "Warren, Oscar J.",
    "ObjectClass": "user",
    "mail": "Oscar.Warren@domain.local"
  },
  {
    "DistinguishedName": "CN=Bodden\\, John B.,OU=Users,OU=Finance Division,OU=Departments,DC=domain,DC=local",
    "Name": "Bodden, John B.",
    "ObjectClass": "user",
    "mail": "John.Bodden@domain.local"
  }
]
```

In an Ansible Playbook I need to loop through the list of **ProgA_Users** and find all ProgB_Users with no matching `mail` attribute.

I tried the following YAML:

```yaml
- name: Process Users
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.userName }}"
  loop: "{{ ProgA_Users.Resources }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: item
  when: "{{ ad_users.objects|selectattr('mail','equalto','{{ item.emails[0].value }}')|list|length == 0 }}"
```

The problem is that Ansible is running the debug task on ALL objects, even when there **is** a matching member within **ProgB_User**.

I want the `debug` task to execute each time Ansible comes across a member of **ProgA_Users** that is not in **ProgB_Users**. The two arrays have objects with different schemas, so I am matching `{ProgA_User}.emails[0].value` against `{ProgB_User}.mail`. The match should not be case-sensitive.

How can I achieve this outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task below

```yaml
    - name: Find all ProgB_Users with no matching mail attribute
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ProgB_Users|rejectattr('mail', 'in', emails) }}"
      loop: "{{ ProgA_Users.Resources }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ emails }}"
      vars:
        emails: "{{ item.emails|map(attribute='value')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [Find all ProgB_Users with no matching mail attribute] ************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Oscar.Warren@domain.local']) => 
  msg:
  - DistinguishedName: CN=Bodden,OU=Departments,DC=domain,DC=local
    Name: Bodden, John B.
    ObjectClass: user
    mail: John.Bodden@domain.local
ok: [localhost] => (item=['Alexandra.Savage@domain.local']) => 
  msg:
  - DistinguishedName: CN=Warren,OU=Departments,DC=domain,DC=local
    Name: Warren, Oscar J.
    ObjectClass: user
    mail: Oscar.Warren@domain.local
  - DistinguishedName: CN=Bodden,OU=Departments,DC=domain,DC=local
    Name: Bodden, John B.
    ObjectClass: user
    mail: John.Bodden@domain.local
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    ProgA_Users:
      Resources:
        - emails:
            - type: work
              value: Oscar.Warren@domain.local
          id: 2939XYZ
          userName: Oscar.Warren@domain.local@SOMEREALM
        - emails:
            - type: work
              value: Alexandra.Savage@domain.local
          id: 2032XYZ
          userName: Alexandra.Savage@domain.local@SOMEREALM

    ProgB_Users:
      - DistinguishedName: CN=Warren,OU=Departments,DC=domain,DC=local
        Name: Warren, Oscar J.
        ObjectClass: user
        mail: Oscar.Warren@domain.local
      - DistinguishedName: CN=Bodden,OU=Departments,DC=domain,DC=local
        Name: Bodden, John B.
        ObjectClass: user
        mail: John.Bodden@domain.local

  tasks:

    - name: Find all ProgB_Users with no matching mail attribute
      debug:
        msg: "{{ ProgB_Users|rejectattr('mail', 'in', emails) }}"
      loop: "{{ ProgA_Users.Resources }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ emails }}"
      vars:
        emails: "{{ item.emails|map(attribute='value')|list }}"
```